# Uncaught ReferenceError: functionXXX is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

In my selenium automation test, I am using remote webdriver and trying to launch a html file as below. The HTML page opens correctly, but at the last part of the code, I am trying to click on a submit button which calls a javascript function (ActionDeterminator()). When that button is clicked to call the js function (ActionDeterminator()), then I see an error in console which I have mentioned at the bottom part.

Below is the html:

```
String butNowButton = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN>" +
        "<HTML><HEAD>" +
        "<META http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html'; charset='UTF-8'>" +
        "<META content='MSHTML 6.00.2900.3157' name='GENERATOR'></HEAD>" +
        "<BODY>" +
        "<H1>Hello It's a testing page</H1>" +
        "<HR>" +

        "<P>Enter the following fields and press the button to initiate Transaction" +
        "transaction</P>" +
        "<FORM name=SSO action='' method='post'>" +
        "<TABLE border='1'>" +
        "  <TBODY>" +
        "  <TR>" +
        "    <TD>Name(*): </TD>" +
        "    <TD><INPUT title='Name' value='Adam' name='Name'>" +
        "  </TD></TR>" +
        "  <TR>" +

       "    <TH colSpan='2'><INPUT id='btnSubmit' onclick='return ActionDeterminator();' type='submit' value='Go to Content catalog' name='btnSubmit'>" +
        "    </TH></TR></TBODY></TABLE>" +
        "    <INPUT type=hidden value='https://someUrl/' name='HOOK_URL'>" +
        "</FORM>" +
        "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript' name='JavaScript'>" +
        "function ActionDeterminator()" +
        "{" +
        "document.SSO.action=document.SSO.URL.value+'/Buyer/Main/ad/somePath/DirectAction';" +
        "alert('URL is ==>'+document.SSO.action);" +
        "document.SSO.submit();" +

        "}" +

        "</SCRIPT>" +

        "<HR>" +
        "</BODY></HTML>";
  //Below is the quick code to use above html and launch a page. This also //works fine, ( in the sense, html page is opened).

  String htmlDiv = "var div=document.createElement('div');div.innerHTML=\"" + butNowButton + "\";arguments[0].appendChild(div);";

System.err.println("***" + htmlDiv);
//'dr' is basically remote webdriver.
WebElement element = dr.findElementsByTagName("BODY").get(0);

dr.executeScript(htmlDiv, element);

//below code tries to invoke function ActionDeterminator().
dr.executeScript("document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();","");
```

And in the console I see below error:

```
data:,:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ActionDeterminator is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (data:,:1)
    at <anonymous>:248:70
    at callFunction (<anonymous>:237:33)
    at <anonymous>:247:23
    at <anonymous>:248:3
onclick @ data:,:1
(anonymous) @ VM50:248
callFunction @ VM50:237
(anonymous) @ VM50:247
(anonymous) @ VM50:248
data:,:1 Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately got it figured. None of the solutions provided here worked, hence I changed the html and calling the function using eval() block. This has worked for me.Just adding this for others' help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the onclick event handler in the DOM, you should put the `ActionDeterminator` function definition in the `<head>` or the window.onload event's callback.

Comment: No, not inside the `window.onload` callback. The function needs to be in global scope. _Inside_ the `window.onload` callback is no longer global scope.

Comment: In window.onload, you need code like `window.onload=function(){window.ActionDeterminator=function(){};};`

Comment: @JiangangXiong, I mentioned like this, but I still see same error.

`dr.executeScript("window.onload=function(){window.ActionDeterminator=function(){};};","");



 dr.executeScript("document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();","");`

Comment: @JiangangXiong Why would you set a function as a `window` property? Just put it in global scope, or don’t use `onclick` attributes at all and instead use the standard `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Xufox , could you pls give me an example.

Comment: You should move this function definition into the `<head>`, your code:"<SCRIPT type='text/javascript' name='JavaScript'>" +
        "function ActionDeterminator()" +
        "{" +
        "document.SSO.action=document.SSO.URL.value+'/Buyer/Main/ad/somePath/DirectAction';" +
        "alert('URL is ==>'+document.SSO.action);" +
        "document.SSO.submit();" +

        "}" +

        "</SCRIPT>" +

Comment: @JiangangXiong, I moved the script inside <HEAD>, but still doesn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in console of browser devtool, it report same error, even I tried JQuery.click() or addEventLister('click'), both not work.

Seems browser not support below behaviour natively: 
the element's event script is added to element dynamically after the page had loaded.

So this issue is not related to Selenium,  browser self not support that natively.